# How to select specific information from a file? Python

Tags: python

I have just started using this new program which outputs in an odd format as shown below:

```
CRISPR 10   Range: 7784249 - 7784543
POSITION    REPEAT              SPACER
--------    --------------------------------    ---------------------------------
7784249     GTTTCAATCCACGCCCCCGCATGGGGGGCGAC    GTTAAGATTTTCAGCCGAAGCATAAGACTGCTCA  [ 32, 34 ]
7784315     GTTTCAATCCACGCCCCCGCATGGGGGGCGAC    ATCAATAACAATACCTTGCTTTTCAGTTTCATT   [ 32, 33 ]
7784380     GTTTCAATCCACGCCCCCGCATGGGGGGCGAC    TATAACTTTCTCCTTCTATTGTTGATGTAACATA  [ 32, 34 ]
7784446     GTTTCAATCCACGCCCCCGCATGGGGGGCGAC    TTTTCATTTGCATCAAGTTCTTTTTCAAGGTCAA  [ 32, 34 ]
7784512     GTTTCAATCCACGCCCCCG>CONTIG-97480    
--------    --------------------------------    ---------------------------------
Repeats: 5  Average Length: 32      Average Length: 33



CRISPR 11   Range: 8822044 - 8822520
POSITION    REPEAT              SPACER
--------    -------------------------------------   ------------------------------------
8822044     GTGTCAATGCCCTATATCGGGCGCACTTCATTTCTAC   TTTACCAATCTCGGCTCTTTACTCCCGCTGGGTGCATT  [ 37, 38 ]
8822119     GTGTCAATGCCCTATATCGGGCGCACTTCATTTCTAC   TTAAAGCAGATACAAAGAAGCCTTGTGAGGAATATT    [ 37, 36 ]
8822192     GTGTCAATGCCCTATATCGGGCGCACTTCATTTCTAC   TATACTTCAGAAGTGCTGAGTTCCAGAAGCTTTTT [ 37, 35 ]
8822264     GTGTCAATGCCCTATATCGGGCGCACTTCATTTCTAC   AAATATATGATTAATAATAAGAATAATCAAATAGTA    [ 37, 36 ]
8822337     GTGTCAATGCCCTATATCGGGCGCACTTCATTTCTAC   TTTCGTGGTTCCATCTGCTTATGAAACATTATTGATCT  [ 37, 38 ]
8822412     GTGTCAATGCCCTATATCGGGCGCACTTCATTTCTAC   GGATGAGGCTGGTACATATACGTACCTGGTTCTTC [ 37, 35 ]
8822484     GTGTCAATGCCCTATATCGGGCGCACTTCAT>CONTI   
--------    -------------------------------------   ------------------------------------
Repeats: 7  Average Length: 37      Average Length: 36
```

I was wondering how I would go about selecting only the third column strings and print them to a new file. I also want to give each  part a title as well for the next program so for example the output for the first line of 'CRISPR 11':

```
>CRISPR_11_8822044_8822520_1
TTTACCAATCTCGGCTCTTTACTCCCGCTGGGTGCATT
```

That way the name is made of up '>' then the number of the CRISPR, then the range values and the final number is where it is in the order e.g. its 1 as it is the first in this set.

I know how to write to a file but no idea how to select the relative parts of the file.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Use str.split() and regex and strip()/lstrip()/rstrip().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, like NewWorld's comment, is just a bunch of regex, splits and list parsing. Though I'm sure there are much more concise and clearer ways of doing this, it's how I'd do it in your position.

This code runs through the input file line by line,

- If the line begins letter 'C', or it is the end of the file, certain strings from the line are picked for assigning the name
- If the line starts with a number, picks out the second string in that line that contains A/T/G/C at least 5 times. You can change this regex if you never want to pick out strings ending CONTI

I saved your text into a file *example.txt*, and ran this.

```
import re

secondbases = []
with open('/example.txt','r') as contents:
    for line in contents:
        splitline = line.split()
        if line[0] == 'C': #If line begins CRISPR, write new info to file and save new CRISP values
            if secondbases != []:
                outputfile = open('/output.txt','a') #With ain't workin for me here, but replace at your own desire
                x = 1
                for base in secondbases:
                    outputfile.write('>CRISPR_' + crispno + '_' + rangestart + '_' + rangeend + '_' +  str(x) + ' ' + base + '\n')
                    x += 1
                outputfile.close()
            secondbases = []
            (crispno,rangestart,rangeend) = (splitline[1],splitline[3],splitline[5])
        elif re.search('[0-9]',line[0]): #If base lines, copy second base string to list
            bases = []
            for a in splitline:
                if re.search('[GTCA]{5,}',a):
                    bases = bases + [a]
            if len(bases) > 1:
                secondbases = secondbases + [bases[1]]
        elif line[len(line)-1] != '\n' and secondbases != []:
            outputfile = open('/output.txt','a')
            x = 1
            for base in secondbases:
                outputfile.write('>CRISPR_' + crispno + '_' + rangestart + '_' + rangeend + '_' +  str(x) + ' ' + base + '\n')
                x += 1
            outputfile.close()
```

Which outputted a file containing

```
>CRISPR_10_7784249_7784543_1 GTTAAGATTTTCAGCCGAAGCATAAGACTGCTCA
>CRISPR_10_7784249_7784543_2 ATCAATAACAATACCTTGCTTTTCAGTTTCATT
>CRISPR_10_7784249_7784543_3 TATAACTTTCTCCTTCTATTGTTGATGTAACATA
>CRISPR_10_7784249_7784543_4 TTTTCATTTGCATCAAGTTCTTTTTCAAGGTCAA
>CRISPR_11_8822044_8822520_1 TTTACCAATCTCGGCTCTTTACTCCCGCTGGGTGCATT
>CRISPR_11_8822044_8822520_2 TTAAAGCAGATACAAAGAAGCCTTGTGAGGAATATT
>CRISPR_11_8822044_8822520_3 TATACTTCAGAAGTGCTGAGTTCCAGAAGCTTTTT
>CRISPR_11_8822044_8822520_4 AAATATATGATTAATAATAAGAATAATCAAATAGTA
>CRISPR_11_8822044_8822520_5 TTTCGTGGTTCCATCTGCTTATGAAACATTATTGATCT
>CRISPR_11_8822044_8822520_6 GGATGAGGCTGGTACATATACGTACCTGGTTCTTC
```

Just make sure that there is a file called *output.txt* or whatever you change it to, otherwise exceptions and whatnot.